# Can I avoid repeated code when nesting two case statements in Elm?

Tags: case, elm

I'm converting a `Maybe String` into a `Date`. I've type aliased `Date` as `Birthdate` for readability.

```
birthdate_from_url : Url.Url -> Birthdate
birthdate_from_url url =
    case url.query of
        Just query ->
            case Date.fromIsoString query of 
                Ok birthdate ->
                    birthdate

                Err _ ->
                    defaultBirthdate

        Nothing ->
            defaultBirthdate
```

With this nested case I'm having to call `defaultBirthdate` twice for each of the possible "failures".

Is there an alternative approach with or without the use of `case`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Maybe.map`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe#map):

```
birthdate_from_url : Url.Url -> Birthdate
birthdate_from_url url =
    case url.query |> Maybe.map Date.fromIsoString of
        Just (Ok birthdate) ->
            birthdate

        _ ->
            defaultBirthdate
```